# Writing a program calculating exponents

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to write a program that prints the results of the exponents of the number 2 and I want to print it out 10 times. I want to create a a method that calculates the value of the exponents using the Math.pow(x,y) method.

2 to the power of 0 = 1 
2 to the power of 1 = 2 
2 to the power of 2 = 4

I have a couple of questions. Can you use the Math.pow method in a for loop like I did below? How do you declare the value of x and y in the method Math.pow(x, y) inside a for loop or do you have to do it outside a for loop? Also, in the raiseIntPower method in Eclipse when I use int n as a parameter it gives me a "duplicate local variable error." My understanding is the method parameters specifies the argument the method requires.  I don't understand the meaning of that duplicate error.

```
import acm.program.*;


public class Exponents extends ConsoleProgram {

  public void run(){
      for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {

            println("2 to the power of " + n + " = " + raiseIntPower(n)); 

     } 

  }
private int raiseIntPower (int n){
   int total = 0;
   for( int n = 0; n <= 10; n++){
     total = Math.pow(2, n);

  } 

return total; 
  }
}
```

Comment: println("2 to the power of " + n + " = " + Math.pow(2, n));

Comment: I want the method raiseIntPower to calculate the result of the exponent of 2 and I want the value of the exponent to raise by 1 until it reaches 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont understand what are you trying to do

just replace the statement

```
println("2 to the power of " + n + " = " + raiseIntPower(n));
```

with

```
println("2 to the power of " + n + " = " + Math.pow(2,n));
```

and it should do it , no need for `raiseIntPower()`

I think you are confused about the usage of `Math.pow()` , please refer here for clarifications [Math.pow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29)

Answer (score 1):

`Math#pow(double a, double b)` where a is the base and b is the exponent, `ab` and it returns double so if you want to discard precision then you have to format return value.

you can remove raiseIntPower method.

```
for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {
     println("2 to the power of " + n + " = " + Math.pow(2,n)); 
}
```

Comment: We have to create a method called raiseIntPower that takes two integers n and k and returns n to the power of k. Then use the method to display a table of value for 2 to the power of k from 0 - 10

Comment: `Math class` it self provide a function `pow` to do that.

Comment: Do I need to use a for loop in the raiseIntPower to calculate the value 10 different times?

Comment: See when times came into picture you have to take a help of loop. :)

Answer (score 0):

check this one

```
import acm.program.*;

public class Exponents extends ConsoleProgram {

  public void run(){
      for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {

            println("2 to the power of " + n + " = " + raiseIntPower(n)); 

     } 

  }
private int raiseIntPower (int n){
   int total = 0;   
   total = (int)Math.pow(2, n);

   return total; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse gives you a "duplicate local variable error" because there is a duplicate variable.

```
private int raiseIntPower (int n){
    int total = 0;
    for( int n = 0; n <= 10; n++){
        total = Math.pow(2, n);
    } 
    return total; 
}
```

You declared a variable n for input. In the for loop, you declared another variable n. The `int n` and references to it in the for loop should be changed to another name, such as `int i`.